# Need data type conversion to json. Tried json.dumps, json.loads, chnges to string not json type

Tags: json, python-3.x

The issue is that no matter what I try the code running on server end requires JSON data only.
I don't get why it can't take dictionary as such.
You can see the issue if you run the code below:

```
...
import json
data={"name":"Picco"}
print(data);
print(type(data));
data1=json.dumps(data);
print(data1);
print(type(data1))
obj = json.loads(data1)
print(obj)
print(type(obj))
#Output
{'name': 'Picco'}
<class 'dict'>
{"name": "Picco"}
<class 'str'>
{'name': 'Picco'}
<class 'dict'>
```

Comment: I didn't really understand the problem. You can't make a request on a Rest API? Do you have the server logs and the request sent? This will help to answer

Comment: Both, https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html and the fact that {"name":"Picco"} is valid JSON, suggest that the error might be caused somewhere else rather than in the code that you provided.

Comment: What server are you using? Flask? If yes, do you confuse mimetype with static type (cf. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.is_json)? Where does the error arise in particular? Can we see the code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Needed to convert it to dictionary again using a simple input as string by using (")ie.

```
data="{"name":"Picco"}"
data1=json.dumps(data)
data2=json.loads(data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 1** Unfortunately, your question is too vague for me (or anyone else) to help you with your problem. Please be more accurate. When you say that your code--which you are not willing to share with us--requires json, do you mean a python json type? Can you at least share the function/method declaration or lib you are using with us so we can try to infer the actual problem?

---

Tested on my side and the code you pasted is the expected result according to the official python docs.

```
>>> import json
>>> data={"name":"Picco"}
>>> data1=json.dumps(data)
>>> type(data1)
<class 'str'>
```

[Source](http://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: this code is just to recreate the problem that I am facing. Actual code is different and I cannot share here. Just know that it requires json, but it does not work with either dict which ideally it should nor with with json created with json.dumps

Comment: @Rahul What do you mean by "it requires json"? According to the *official docs* `json.dumps` is supposed to return `str` type. Please be more specific on your issue or no one will be able to help.